# How to achieve tree view in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

I would like to create a tree view from json data, I found a package [Graph View](https://pub.dev/packages/graphview) and tried to implement it and failed to generate view from json data.

my database has died as follows

- Name
- ParentID
- ChilID

Current Output
[image]

This is my current code

```
 List<Tree> _treeList = [];
    
      void generate() {
        _treeList.add(Tree(text: 'one',pid: 1,cid: 2));
        _treeList.add(Tree(text: 'two',pid: 1,cid: 3));
        _treeList.add(Tree(text: 'three',pid: 2,cid: 4));
        _treeList.add(Tree(text: 'four',pid: 2,cid: 5));
        _treeList.add(Tree(text: 'five',pid: 2,cid: 6));
        _treeList.add(Tree(text: 'six',pid: 2,cid: 6));
        _treeList.add(Tree(text: 'seven',pid: 2,cid: 8));
        _treeList.add(Tree(text: 'eight',pid: 4,cid: 9));
        _treeList.add(Tree(text: 'nine',pid: 4,cid: 10));
        _treeList.add(Tree(text: 'ten',pid: 4,cid: 11));
        _treeList.add(Tree(text: 'eleven',pid: 11,cid: 12));
        _treeList.add(Tree(text: 'twelve',pid: 11,cid: 13));
      }
    void loadData()async {
    await generate();
    for (var i in _treeList) {
    
   
     graph.addEdge(Node(getNodeText(i.text,i.pid,i.cid)),Node(getNodeText(i.text,i.pid,i.cid)));

//in graph.addEdge(parent Data,Child Data); , this is what I am looking to achieve so it can generate tree view
    }
    
      builder
        ..siblingSeparation = (100)
        ..levelSeparation = (150)
        ..subtreeSeparation = (150)
        ..orientation = BuchheimWalkerConfiguration.ORIENTATION_TOP_BOTTOM;
    
    }
```

This package require to have a parent and child node to be passed. but with this code gives me error as follows

```
flutter: Node{position: Offset(0.0, 0.0), data: Container(padding: EdgeInsets.all(16.0), bg:
    BoxDecoration(borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(4.0),
      boxShadow: [BoxShadow(Color(0xffbbdefb), Offset(0.0, 0.0), 0.0,
        1.0)]
      )
  ), _size: Size(441.0, 89.0)} is not connected to primary ancestor
flutter: Node{position: Offset(0.0, 0.0), data: Container(padding: EdgeInsets.all(16.0), bg:
    BoxDecoration(borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(4.0),
      boxShadow: [BoxShadow(Color(0xffbbdefb), Offset(0.0, 0.0), 0.0,
        1.0)]
      )
  ), _size: Size(489.0, 89.0)} is not connected to primary ancestor
flutter: Node{position: Offset(0.0, 0.0), data: Container(padding: EdgeInsets.all(16.0), bg:
    BoxDecoration(borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(4.0),
      boxShadow: [BoxShadow(Color(0xffbbdefb), Offset(0.0, 0.0), 0.0,
        1.0)]
      )
  ), _size: Size(457.0, 89.0)} is not connected to primary ancestor
flutter: Node{position: Offset(0.0, 0.0), data: Container(padding: EdgeInsets.all(16.0), bg:
    BoxDecoration(borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(4.0),
      boxShadow: [BoxShadow(Color(0xffbbdefb), Offset(0.0, 0.0), 0.0,
        1.0)]
      )
  ), _size: Size(448.0, 89.0)} is not connected to primary ancestor
flutter: Node{position: Offset(0.0, 0.0), data: Container(padding: EdgeInsets.all(16.0), bg:
    BoxDecoration(borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(4.0),
      boxShadow: [BoxShadow(Color(0xffbbdefb), Offset(0.0, 0.0), 0.0,
        1.0)]
      )
  ), _size: Size(427.0, 89.0)} is not connected to primary ancestor
flutter: Node{position: Offset(0.0, 0.0), data: Container(padding: EdgeInsets.all(16.0), bg:
    BoxDecoration(borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(4.0),
      boxShadow: [BoxShadow(Color(0xffbbdefb), Offset(0.0, 0.0), 0.0,
        1.0)]
      )
  ), _size: Size(502.0, 89.0)} is not connected to primary ancestor
flutter: Node{position: Offset(0.0, 0.0), data: Container(padding: EdgeInsets.all(16.0), bg:
    BoxDecoration(borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(4.0),
      boxShadow: [BoxShadow(Color(0xffbbdefb), Offset(0.0, 0.0), 0.0,
        1.0)]
      )
  ), _size: Size(487.0, 89.0)} is not connected to primary ancestor
flutter: Node{position: Offset(0.0, 0.0), data: Container(padding: EdgeInsets.all(16.0), bg:
    BoxDecoration(borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(4.0),
      boxShadow: [BoxShadow(Color(0xffbbdefb), Offset(0.0, 0.0), 0.0,
        1.0)]
      )
  ), _size: Size(491.0, 89.0)} is not connected to primary ancestor
flutter: Node{position: Offset(0.0, 0.0), data: Container(padding: EdgeInsets.all(16.0), bg:
    BoxDecoration(borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(4.0),
      boxShadow: [BoxShadow(Color(0xffbbdefb), Offset(0.0, 0.0), 0.0,
        1.0)]
      )
  ), _size: Size(456.0, 89.0)} is not connected to primary ancestor
flutter: Node{position: Offset(0.0, 0.0), data: Container(padding: EdgeInsets.all(16.0), bg:
    BoxDecoration(borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(4.0),
      boxShadow: [BoxShadow(Color(0xffbbdefb), Offset(0.0, 0.0), 0.0,
        1.0)]
      )
  ), _size: Size(563.0, 89.0)} is not connected to primary ancestor
flutter: Node{position: Offset(0.0, 0.0), data: Container(padding: EdgeInsets.all(16.0), bg:
    BoxDecoration(borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(4.0),
      boxShadow: [BoxShadow(Color(0xffbbdefb), Offset(0.0, 0.0), 0.0,
        1.0)]
      )
  ), _size: Size(569.0, 89.0)} is not connected to primary ancestor
```

any help will be highly appreciated, also suggest me if there is an alternative way to achieve the same

Comment: "_tried to implement it and failed_" is not a problem description. _What_ code did you write? _How_ did it fail? Also, requests for recommendations are defined as off-topic,

Comment: @underscore_d  I have added my code

Comment: Great! Now you just also need to explain what happens when you run it, and why that's bad. "failed to generate view" is not clear about what your specific problem is.

Comment: I have commented the point in my code, the package needs a parent and child node. my question is if someone can help me to achieve the same. I have added the error to my question